# How to hide one column in a pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable, csv

How can I hide the column `parameter a` (header and data) of the following table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  columns={Name,{para a},{para b},{para c},{para d}},
  columns/Name/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para a}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para b}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para c}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para d}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  ]{
  Name,para a,para b,para c,para d
  test1,1,2,3,4
  test2,2,3,4,5
  test3,3,4,5,6
  test4,4,5,6,7
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: remove it from the `columns` key.

Comment: Thanks, That worked, So Simple I cant believe I didnt try that,

Comment: @LaRiFaRi What's the rush?

Comment: I'm sorry, shall I delete my answer?

Answer (score 8):

Omitting the key in `columns` removes that column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  columns={Name,{para c},{para d}},
  columns/Name/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para a}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para b}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para c}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  columns/{para d}/.style={column type={r},string type},
  ]{
  Name,para a,para b,para c,para d
  test1,1,2,3,4
  test2,2,3,4,5
  test3,3,4,5,6
  test4,4,5,6,7
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks! [@percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse)