# How to hide one column in a pgfplotstable - directly

Tags: pgfplotstable, columns

Using pgfplotstable I want to print a datatable, it is a quite lengthy (14 columns).

**Now I am wondering how to omit one column from being included into the table.**

A known solution was presented in [How to hide one column in a pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253244/how-to-hide-one-column-in-a-pgfplotstable), however this solution is not very pretty because it actually solves the problem indirectly, i.e., by specifying the columns which are printed (in contrast to the ones omitted).

Since I have 14 columns, this would involve a very lengthy line

> columns={HeadCol1,HeadCol2,HeadCol3,HeadCol4,HeadCol6,HeadCol7,HeadCol8,...}

And the column header names are also still subject to change. So I am looking for a way to just say, omit column with index, e.g, 6. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround. It does not apply if you want hide two or more columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
         A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
        15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
    }\loadedtable

    \ttfamily
    \meaning\loadedtable

    \pgfplotstabletypeset\loadedtable

    \let\newcolumnlist\relax
    \def\dropcolumn{F}
    \pgfplotslistforeach\loadedtable\as\columnname{
        \ifx\columnname\dropcolumn\else
            \ifx\newcolumnlist\relax
                \xdef\newcolumnlist{\columnname}
            \else
                \xdef\newcolumnlist{\newcolumnlist,\columnname}
            \fi
        \fi
    }
    \edef\pgfplotsmarshal{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={\newcolumnlist}]\noexpand\loadedtable}

    \meaning\newcolumnlist

    \pgfplotsmarshal


\end{document}
```

Comment: I will leave this open a bit longer to see if someone comes up with a more 'native' way.

Comment: No problem! If there is no other method I can improve this myself. But before that I want to see people's ideas as well.

Comment: Guess no one has ideas.

Comment: Ha! It has been three years and I understand pgfplots more than before. But deleting things is not what pgfplots is good at.